# How to update YAML files using shell pipes?

Tags: json, shell, yaml

I am looking for a simple UNIX approach for saving data obtained using shell scripts into YAML files, for example I want to save the list of installed packages (rpms, pypi) from the system in a single YAML file using a shell pipes, something like:

rpm -qa | sort | some-yaml-tool manifest.yaml system.packages

The expected results would be a `manifest.yaml` file that would look like:

```
system:
    packages:
        - xz-5.2.2-2.fc24.x86_64
        - xz-devel-5.2.2-2.fc24.x86_64
```

While I prefer YAML, I would not refuse a JSON compatible solution. I am really interested in finding a way to do this with tools that are available on most distributions, not something esoteric that would need to be installed manually or from non-official yum/deb repositories.

If the tool is smart, it should be able to create the file and internal path when it does exist.

Please note that I had to remove `jq` tool from the list because it does [not allow in-place editing](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/105).

Comment: `jq <filename | sponge filename` does in-place editing perfectly well -- whereas the `tempfile=$(mktemp -t "$in.XXXXXX"); jq <"$in" >"$tempfile" && mv "$tempfile" "in"` is portable to pretty much anywhere one might care about. Given as `sed -i` *isn't* portable between GNU and BSD invocations, using an alternate formulation is good habit to be in regardless.

Comment: `jq` is clearly not an option as there are just too many things that can go wrong while trying to implement the missing behavior in a wrapper. Is it extremely easy to end up with broken files. Also performance is another issue, where I don't want to create temp files for each processed line.

Comment: Who said you'd need an instance for each processed line? It's trivial to write jq code that reads a stream of input and modifies the content passed based on multiple pairs or elements from that stream.

Comment: And creating a temp file for each invocation is what `sed -i` (and pretty much every other instance of in-place editing) does under-the-hood. You're not reducing your number of transient temporary files by having them by created by a separate tool on your behalf rather than by your own code.

Comment: Keep in mind that support for in-place edits is extremely limited at the underlying syscall-interface level (content modified in-place needs to have the same length both before and after the operation, unless you're appending or truncating), so if you're expecting `sed -i` or a similar tool to *not* create a temporary file, you're expecting it to buffer an unknown amount of content in memory (*and* to risk your data's integrity by having content not exist in a complete and consistent state while the edit is ongoing). That's not feasible for a tool that needs to support files larger than RAM.

Answer (score 1):

#### Inserting package names into a YAML file

You don't need in-place editing support for your intended use case at all. Noting that YAML is a superset of JSON, and thus that all output from `jq` is also valid YAML:

```
rpm -qa | sort | jq -Rn '{"system": {"packages": [inputs]}}'
```

will generate an output file of the form:

```
{
  "system": {
    "packages": [
      "bar",
      "baz",
      "foo"
    ]
  }
}
```

...in only a single pass. To make this more idiomatic YAML, you can parse through a tiny Python shim using the PyYAML library:

```
yaml_format() {
  python -c 'import sys, yaml; sys.stdout.write(yaml.dump(yaml.load(sys.stdin), default_flow_style=False))'
}
rpm -qa | sort | jq -Rn '{"system": {"packages": [inputs]}}' | yaml_format
```

...will generate content of the form:

```
system:
  packages:
  - bar
  - baz
  - foo
```

---

#### Updating a JSON file in-place

Let's say you already have a JSON file with content *other than* the manifest that you want to preserve. In that case, the question asked explicitly becomes relevant. A safe (albeit GNU-only) implementation would look like the following:

```
atomic_update() {
  # usage: atomic_update filename command arg1 arg2 ...
  local filename tempfile retval=0
  filename=$1; shift || return
  tempfile=$(mktemp -t -- "$filename.XXXXXX") || return
  if "$@" <"$filename" >"$tempfile"; then
    # Make a best-effort attempt to preserve permissions
    chown --reference="$filename" -- "$tempfile" &>/dev/null ||:
    chmod --reference="$filename" -- "$tempfile" &>/dev/null ||:
    mv -- "$tempfile" "$filename"
  else
    retval=$?
    rm -f -- "$tempfile"
  fi
  return "$retval"
}

rpm -qa | sort | atomic_update manifest.yml jq -Rn '.system.packages = [inputs]'
```

Comment: It seems that the atomic_update part does not work on Mac OS, still trying to find out why.

Comment: Throws some errors because I put the redirections to quiet stderr (when you didn't have chown and chmod with GNU extensions) at the wrong place, but it does appear to work on 10.12.6 even with the original code. `printf '%s\n' 2 3 1 >test.txt; atomic_update test.txt sort` leaves `test.txt` sorted even on OS X. (Caveat is that without GNU chmod, the new `test.txt` can have different file permissions than the old one).

Answer (score 0):

While I do not have yet fully working solution, I think I am very close to finding one via the `json` npm packages.

```
echo "{}" > e.json
seq 3 | xargs -0 -I XXX json -I -f e.json -e 'this.numbers=XXX'
cat e.json
```

The only part the is missing now is about how to make it use a list and merging to it instead of overriding values.

Comment: `seq 3` doesn't use NUL delimiters, so what's with the `-0` argument to `xargs`? And if this *weren't* called with `-0`, it would be calling `json` *once per sequence number*. Inasmuch as you indicated concern about performance in the question, that strikes me as making this approach generally infeasible (particularly when used not for a sequence of three integers but one with hundreds of package names).

Comment: sea 3 was only for quick testing. I am going to test it as soon I get the the computer, looks as doing the right thing.